# How to load a file into a html5 audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

How would a I load a audio file from a `<input type="file">` tag into a audio tag?
I have tried :

```
<input type="file" id="file"></input>
<script>
var file = document.getElementById("file");
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = file.value;
document.write(audio)
</script>
```

Comment: So you want to select a file with a file input and once it's selected load it into an audio tag?

Comment: You are going to need to upload that file first most likely... When selecting with a file input, you only have a path reference to the file on your computer, and even though you may be using this on a local setup, your script is executing  with it's own root. The data given by the input is just a path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe it will satisfy your needs. First, the file input needs to be bound via JavaScript or jQuery (if you prefer). You can use [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) <sup>[browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls)</sup>

The following is a very basic example;

```
<input type="file" id="file"></input>
<audio id="audio" controls autoplay></audio>
```

We bind the `#file` for changes using `AddEventListener` as below

```
// Check for BlobURL support
var blob = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    if (!blob) {
        console.log('Your browser does not support Blob URLs :(');
        return;           
    }

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function(event){

        consolePrint('change on input#file triggered');
        var file = this.files[0],
         fileURL = blob.createObjectURL(file);
        console.log(file);
        console.log('File name: '+file.name);
        console.log('File type: '+file.type);
        console.log('File BlobURL: '+ fileURL);
        document.getElementById('audio').src = fileURL;

});
```

Or the other hand, here's a [nice and more interactive example](http://jsfiddle.net/adamazad/0oy5moph/) I created

```html
<iframe style="height:600px;width:102.7%;margin:-10px;overflow:hidden;" src="//jsfiddle.net/adamazad/0oy5moph/embedded/result,js,html,css/" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
    var file = document.getElementById("file");
    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    file.onchange = function() {
        audio.src = file.value;
        wrap.appendChild(audio);
    };
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <input type="file" id="file">
</div>
```

This is to realize the train of thought, but this also cannot achieve, because  url that the upload is not local url,  You can discuss with me in the comments section

Comment: Well I figured it out what I did was I converted the audio file to base64 the set the source to equal the base64 string

Answer (score 0):

I have developed an es6 code to load a file into an Audio element with a Promise that catches errors and resolves on success

```js
    //functions:

    function setSrcObject(element, f) {
    if ('srcObject' in element) {
      try {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        element.srcObject = f; // this is the new way. only safary supports muliplt inputs, it is possible to put here media streams and files and blobs, but current new browsers support only media stream so need a fallback.
      } catch (e) {
        if (e.name !== 'TypeError') throw e;
        // Avoid using this in new browsers, as it is going away.
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        element.src = URL.createObjectURL(f);
      }
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    else element.src = URL.createObjectURL(f);
  }

  function loadAudioFile(audio, file) {
    let onloadeddataResolve;
    let onloadeddataReject;
    // once
    function onloadeddataEv() {
      onloadeddataResolve();
      audio.removeEventListener('loadeddata', onloadeddataEv);
      audio.removeEventListener('error', onerrorEv);
    }
    function onerrorEv(e) {
      onloadeddataReject(e.srcElement.error);
      audio.removeEventListener('loadeddata', onloadeddataEv);
      audio.removeEventListener('error', onerrorEv);
    }
    audio.addEventListener('loadeddata', onloadeddataEv);
    audio.addEventListener('error', onerrorEv);
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      onloadeddataResolve = resolve;
      onloadeddataReject = reject;
    }); // inversion of control promise
    // try load it:
    try {
      // audio.src =  url; // = http://example.org/myfile.mp3 or .ogg
      setSrcObject(audio, file);
      audio.load();
    } catch (e) {
      audio.removeEventListener('loadeddata', onloadeddataEv);
      audio.removeEventListener('error', onerrorEv);
      onloadeddataReject(e);
    }
    return promise;
  }

//example:

let audio =  new Audio(); // create audio element
audio.autoPlay=false;
filefield.oninput=async function test() {
  try {
    const f =  filefield.files[0]; // take first file 
    await loadAudioFile(audio, f); // load the file
    await audio.play();
  } catch(e) { console.log(e.stack?e.stack:e) }
}
playpause.onclick = async () => {  if( audio.paused) await audio.play(); else await audio.pause(); };
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filefield" multiple="multiple"  accept="audio/mpeg, audio/mp4, audio/ogg">
<input id="playpause" value="play pause" type="button">
```

this solution was a part of a playlist player object I have developed

https://jsfiddle.net/shimondoodkin/7zmhsg30/20/

related solution, play audio using web audio API

https://jsfiddle.net/shimondoodkin/251wx8ys/31/